# Collection of independent sets equal to downset?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-orders

I have been struggling with the following problem.

Every set here is supposed to be finite.

If we have a closure $\lambda$ on $X$, we define the collection of independent sets of $X$ as $$ I_\lambda = \{ A \subseteq X : x \notin\lambda(A\setminus \{ x \})\forall x\in A \} $$

Supose now we have a downset $I \subseteq 2^X$. Is there a closure $\lambda$ on $X$ such that $I_\lambda = I$?

I first tried a pretty straightforward closure, by setting $\lambda(A) = A$ for elements in $I$ and $\lambda(A) = X$ for the rest. This of course does not work but only on a few sets, namely the ones that are not in $I$ but that any $A \setminus \{x\}$ is in $I$ for every $x \in A$, I tried to refine this idea to get rid of those cases but I haven't been able to do it.

This lead to my believe that it may not be possible and probably the trouble sets are those I just mentioned, but on a few small example I have been able to find the closure even when there are sets like those.

**Edit**: Now I know this is not possible, but I need help finding a counterexample, or even better, trying to understand when it exactly fails, and when it works.

Any help is appreciated

**Definitons**

A closure $\lambda$ on $X$ is a function $\lambda: 2^X \to 2^X$, such that is increasing (i.e $A \subseteq \lambda(A)$), monotone and idempotent.

An $I$ is said to be a downset if for any $A \in I$ and $B \subseteq A$, then $B \in I$

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was to try
$$
\lambda(A)=\begin{cases}A,&\text{if $A\cup\{x\}\in I$ for some $x\in X\setminus A$}\\X,&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}
$$
but this does not work (see alejopelaez's comment). Another idea I had was to try something like
$$
\lambda(A)=\{x\in X:\text{$x\in A$ or $A\cup\{x\}\notin I$}\},
$$
but this is not idempotent.

It is possible that an idea from [matroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid) might work. For example, we could take
$$
\lambda(A)=\{x\in X:r(A)=r(A\cup\{x\})\},
$$
where
$$
r(A)=\max\{\lvert B\rvert:\text{$B\subseteq A$ and $B\in I$}\}
$$
is the size of the largest subset of $A$ that is in $I$. The idea is that $r$ is some kind of "rank" function, having the property that $r(A)=\lvert A\rvert$ if and only if $A\in I$.

Comment: I tried that, and it does not work. You can for example take a whole level of $2^X$, and remove one element from it, then consider the downset generated by what is left, then that set you removed will satisfy the condition, but is not in the downset.

Comment: Oh, of course - thanks for pointing that out. Have you already tried something like the matroid idea I edited in? I tried to determine whether or not it works, but I got a bit bogged down in the details.

Comment: I didn't tried using that. But anyway, now I know it is not possible, but I still haven't found a counterexample

Answer (score -1):

Try the closure that have the exchange property.

Comment: Can you expand?

Comment: I am sorry for such short answer, I am still not sure how type in math mode on this forum.

Exchange closure : If x in Cl(A U y)/Cl(A) Then y is in Cl(A U x).

With this closure, you can see that your collection of independent sets satisfy matroid's conditions. Maybe from there, you can get to your down set. 
Just a thought.